# Create a variable with value a boolean

Tags: ruby

I want to know if I can create a variable with a boolean as value, something like this:

```
my_var =
if X > Y
   print "The value is true" 
else
   print "The value is false"
end
```

This is so I can write a boolean easily.

EDIT:

I'm trying to do "shortcuts" using variables that are equal to a boolean. That way, if I require to write a boolean multiple times in a code, I can just "call" the variable.

Example:

```
x = gets.chomp
y = gets.chomp

required_boolean = 
if x > y
puts "x is greater than y"
elsif x = Y
puts "X and Y are equal"
else
puts "y is greater than x"
end

puts "Since x has a value of #{x} and y has a value of {y}, we can say that #{required_boolean}"
```

Comment: I edited the code, but not sure where to put `my_var`.. it is confusing. Please edit and format the code again correctly

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this: `my_var = X > Y` (which will be `true` or `false`), then `my_var ? (print "The value is true") : (print "The value is false")` or `print "The value is #{my_var ? 'true' : 'false'}"`.

Comment: Actually, `true.to_s == "true"`, you could run: `"The value is #{(my_var = (x > y) ).to_s}"`

Answer (score 1):

boolean in ruby supports `#to_s`..

Which means you can do something like this:

```
true.to_s # => "true"
false.to_s # => "false"
(1 < 2).to_s # => "true"
```